# Reactjs variable not defined error when declared inside conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, formik, yup

I am defining my const/var in a if condition and using it but it still says that its not defined. the var/const is userfinal:

```
const uploadPostOnline = async (imageUrl, caption) => {
  const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
  console.log(userId);
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "posts");

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "realusers"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    if (doc.data().owner_uid === userId) {
      var userfinal = doc.data().username;
      console.log(doc.data().username);

    }

  });

  addDoc(collectionRef, {
    imageUrl,
    caption,
    username: userfinal,(NOTE: it says userfinal is not defined)
    likes: 0,
    likesByUsers: [],
    comments: [],
    createdAt: serverTimestamp()
  });
};
```

Comment: You need to declare a non-constant variable _outside_ the callback, and alter it in the callback.

Comment: Could you please write an answer with code, i dont understand what you mean by altering it in callback. Please, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
let userfinal; // 
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "realusers"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  if (doc.data().owner_uid === userId) {
    userfinal = doc.data().username; // 
  }
});

addDoc(collectionRef, {
  imageUrl,
  caption,
  username: userfinal,
  likes: 0,
  likesByUsers: [],
  comments: [],
  createdAt: serverTimestamp()
});
```

---

The way you're selecting the user is *very* inefficient though. You're loading all document from `realusers` to find only one it seems. That's going to cost you more money as you have more users in `realusers`, and is going to be eating up the bandwidth of your users too.

It's better to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to only request the user(s) you need from the database. Something like:

```
const qry = query(collection(db, "realusers"), where("owner_uid", "==", userId));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(qry);
```

Comment: Instead of a for each it'd probably be better to use something like filter, assuming only one value has that username: `const userfinal = querySnapshot.filter((doc) => (doc.data().owner_uid === userId))[0].data().username;`.

Comment: Correct @code.  I already was working on that as an addition to my answer, but decided to post the solution to OPs scoping `userfinal` problem quicker to in hopes of averting further downvotes.